# How can I analyze the value of he first cell in a filtered range? Special Cells?

Tags: excel, range, vba

I am having difficulty checking if the first cell below the header in a filtered column has LT in it.  I believe the Special cells is placed incorrectly.

HeaderRow = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range(1).Row

```
FiltRng = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(HeaderRow  + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).value

        If FiltRng Like "*LT*" Then
MsgBox "It has LT"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can find to achieve this is to check if the first non-header row is visible:

- if so, get the cell from there
- if not, get the next *area* from the visible *SpecialCells*
- if there's only one such area, it's the header row, meaning the autofilter did not match anything and so everything was hidden.

.

```
With wb.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range
  If Not .Rows(2).Hidden Then
    FiltRng = .Cells(2, 1).Value2
  ElseIf .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.count > 1 Then
    FiltRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2).Cells(1, 1).Value2
  Else
    MsgBox "no Cells found"
  End If
  If FiltRng Like "*LT*" Then MsgBox "It has LT"
```

Comment: anyrangeVar.cells(1,1)